# How can I make ExpressValidator validate empty array OR contents of array

Tags: javascript, express-validator

I have an array that passes through my validator, which currently looks like this:

```
expressValidator.body('animals.*').custom(checkAnimal).withMessage('Must provide an array containing valid animals')
```

So if I feed it `['goat','lemming','ocelot']` it will pass, and `['goat','lemming','Buick']` will fail on the last element.

However... an EMPTY array ("[]") is also valid, and I can't figure out how to write that validator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
expressValidator.oneOf([
  expressValidator.body('animals').isArray()
    .withMessage('animals must be an array')
  expressValidator.body('animals.*').custom(checkAnimal)
    .withMessage('Must provide an array containing valid animals')
])
```